Oxyplot Avalonia - error when trying to add StyleIncludes
I am creating an Avalonia application and will be using Oxyplot with it.
According to https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-avalonia the usage requires adding the following code to app.axaml:
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="Sensei.Presentation.Avalonia.App">
    <Application.Styles>
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml"/>
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
      
        <!-- Add the line below to get OxyPlot UI theme applied. -->
        <StyleInclude Source="resm:OxyPlot.Avalonia.Themes.Default.xaml?assembly=OxyPlot.Avalonia"/>
      
        <!-- Add the line below to get OxyPlot UI theme applied in Avalonia 11. -->
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://OxyPlot.Avalonia/Themes/Default.axaml"/>
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>

As such, my file now contains the following:
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="AdProgrammingGUIAvalonia.App"
             RequestedThemeVariant="Default">
             <!-- "Default" ThemeVariant follows system theme variant. "Dark" or "Light" are other available options. -->

    <Application.Styles>
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml"/>
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
      
        <!-- Add the line below to get OxyPlot UI theme applied. -->
        <StyleInclude Source="resm:OxyPlot.Avalonia.Themes.Default.xaml?assembly=OxyPlot.Avalonia"/>
      
        <!-- Add the line below to get OxyPlot UI theme applied in Avalonia 11. -->
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://OxyPlot.Avalonia/Themes/Default.axaml"/>
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>



However, after adding that to the file, i get the following error:
One or more errors occurred. (Assembly "Avalonia.Themes.Default" was not found from the "avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml" source. Line 8, position 23.) (Assembly "Avalonia.Themes.Default" was not found from the "avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" source. Line 9, position 23.) (Unable to resolve "!AvaloniaResources" type on "OxyPlot.Avalonia" assembly. Line 15, position 23.) (Assembly "Avalonia.Themes.Default" was not found from the "avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/DefaultTheme.xaml" source. Line 8, position 23.) (Assembly "Avalonia.Themes.Default" was not found from the "avares://Avalonia.Themes.Default/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" source. Line 9, position 23.) (Unable to resolve "!AvaloniaResources" type on "OxyPlot.Avalonia" assembly. Line 15, position 23.)  AdProgrammingGUIAvalonia    D:\Advanced Programming\Advanced-Programming-Project\AdProgrammingGUIAvalonia\App.axaml         

How can I fix this? The Avalonia version I am using is 11.1.0 and the version of Oxyplot.Avalonia that I am using is 2.1.0-Avalonia11.
